# Finding count of points for which both [x,y] are bigger than given point?

Tags: arrays, search, data-structures

Given a set of x,y co-ordinates (with up to 10^9 different points), and given a Point `P = {x_p, y_p}`, find number of points in this set such that `x_i > x_p` and `y_i > y_p`, where `i` is a `i'th` point in the set. I want to do this for all points in set (in other words p belongs to [1, n]. Where `n` is size of set.

A simple O(n^2) approach is too inefficient with this size of set. Is there any better algorithm or data structure for this kind of problems?

Example:
`S = [(1,10), (7,2), (2,5), (9,4), (3,2)]`

Output
`0 1 0 0 1`.

Explanation: For `(1,10)` there is no such element which has `x > 1` and `y > 10`, hence for `(1,10)` output is 0. However, for `(7,2)` There is one element (`(9,4)`) which satisfies our condition, hence output is `1` for `(7,2)`.

Comment: Just to be clear, all points `{x_p, y_p}` belong to the *same* "set" as `{x_i, y_i}`, and are not just arbitrary test inputs?

Comment: I don't know if Iunderstood your question clearly. But can't you assume that the number of points that satisfy your condition can be calculated by: `(x_n - x_p) * (y_n - y_p)` ?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog You are right! `{x_p, y_p}` is not an arbitrary input. They all belong to same set.

Comment: @GeorgeBou I think you mean we sort the set somehow and then calculate `(x_n - x_p) * (y_n - y_p)`, where `n` is the last element in array. But this does not work as last element might have `x_p < x_n` but `y_p > y_n` or vice versa (depending on how you sort it)

Comment: Maybe you should  give us an input and output example to make it more clear to us.

Comment: @GeorgeBou example added

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the simple solution is O(n^2) ?

Just iterate over the points checking the condition and incrementing a counter which is O(n).